# How to use exec() to display more than one value?

Tags: php, arrays, output, exec

I'm using php function *exec()* to execute a shell script.
The shell script return 3 echo :

```
[.. SCRIPT ..]
echo $mp3
echo "$title"
echo $img
```

How can I recover them separately to use them ?

For now, when I print the output, only $img is printed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your script doesn't return 3 values.

Instead, you echo 3 variables. I think that the 2 first are not initialized.

Comment: It returns a single one with the 2 results inside ?
In fact, I'm trying to improve a previous script.

I was using 3 exec function, with 3 differents scripts, but for performance reasons, I try to use only one exec() with an only script who return 3 values. I don't know if I'm clear ^^

How can I do that ?